# Arrange two spatial maps side by side using ggplot (geom_sf)

Tags: r, ggplot2, layout, coordinates, geospatial

I'd like to arrange two maps, a map of North America with given coordinate limits and a map of Europe with predefined coordinate limits. The maps are created with ggplot's `geom_sf().`

The maps should be arranged side by side in one row. The arranged maps should be of the same height (width of each map might be adjusted accordingly)... I am very close to what I want but I am unsure how to properly adjust heights so that the maps match.

Here an example of code:

```
### Plot Europe an North America side by side
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggspatial)

### Load country maps
europe <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf",
                       continent = "europe")
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")


### Plot maps for continents
Europe <- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill="grey70",color="grey90",size=0.3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-12, 33), ylim = c(40, 65), expand = F,datum = NA)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "grey50", fill=NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "null"))
  
NorthAmerica <- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill="grey70",color="grey90",size=0.3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-127, -52), ylim = c(15, 65), expand = F, datum = NA)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "grey50", fill=NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "null"))

## Arrange maps side by side (e.g. via grid.arrange)
grid.arrange(NorthAmerica, Europe, nrow = 1)
```

and the result with slightly missmatching heights:
[image: Missmatching maps]

What I could do is to manually tweak the limits in `coord_sf`, but I'll probably never get it to a real fit of heights, as the limits are given in degrees rather than metric units (which would need proper geospatial transformation).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to switch to the `patchwork` package:

```r
library(patchwork)

NorthAmerica + Europe
```

[image]